# Automatically merge with union strategy during rebase

Tags: windows, git, merge, rebase, gitattributes

I want to  automatically merge .csproj files when doing `git rebase` by keeping all added lines:

```
mkdir example
cd example

git init
echo "*.csproj text merge=union" > .gitattributes
echo "hello" > sample.csproj
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"

git branch test
git checkout test
echo "from test" >> sample.csproj
git add -A
git commit -m "from test"

git checkout master
echo "from master" >> sample.csproj
git add -A
git commit -m "from master"

git rebase test
```

There are two problems. First, this fails with a binary warning :

```
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
warning: Cannot merge binary files: sample.csproj (HEAD vs. from master)
Auto-merging sample.csproj
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sample.csproj
Failed to merge in the changes.
```

The second problem is on my other repo it correct determines the file is text (not sure why) but still fails the merge.

```
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging Source/App/TRPS.Build/TRPS.Build.csproj
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Source/App/TRPS.Build/TRPS.Build.csproj
Failed to merge in the changes.
```

Comment: The first script works for me (Ubuntu, Git 1.9.3), after I changed `md` to `mkdir`. Are you on Windows? What are your CRLF settings?